# "Post your question" button is disabled, why?

Tags: support

I want to ask a question on Stack Overflow, but the "post your question" button is disabled. And also when entering tags, [intellisense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion) does not appear.

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser's cache and double-checking in the console that all the Javascript resources are correctly loaded?

Comment: If you browse directly to the [ask a question page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) what you get?

Comment: I closed browser and opened the page again and it worked. Thanks a lot for your kind help :)

Comment: Clearing the cache in Chrome did the trick